# SQL Query to find percentage difference in salary by emp id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (in_date date, emp_id int , salary int);

INSERT INTO test1 (in_date, emp_id, salary)
VALUES
('01-01-2020',1,4000),
('01-01-2020',2,3000),
('01-01-2020',3,6000),
('01-01-2020',4,9000),
('02-01-2020',1,2000),
('02-01-2020',2,5000),
('02-01-2020',3,4200),
('02-01-2020',4,8500);
```

| In_date | emp_id | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 1 | 4000 |
| 01-01-2020 | 2 | 3000 |
| 01-01-2020 | 3 | 6000 |
| 01-01-2020 | 4 | 9000 |
| 02-01-2020 | 1 | 2000 |
| 02-01-2020 | 2 | 5000 |
| 02-01-2020 | 3 | 4200 |
| 02-01-2020 | 4 | 8500 |

I would like to calculate percentage change in salary per emp_id

The output should look like this

| emp_id | per_diff_salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50% |
| 2 | -67% |
| 3 | 30% |
| 4 | 6% |

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Tables in a relational database have no default order, you have nothing in your data to indicate which is the first or second value for each Id.

Comment: Hi Stu, I apologize for the ambiguity in my question. Please assume we have a date field and the dates are in ascending order.

Comment: If that's that case, why is it not part your sample data? Your question needs to contain everything that is relevant.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Lease don't close my question this is my last hope. I have edited the question

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=533b8ea5a9fefde9bb520386afa069bd

Comment: Aside: I would have expected a salary that increases over time would be considered a _positive_ difference. You must be calculating from the employer's perspective.

Comment: @Stu Looks like it could be reopened now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ROW_NUMBER` to identify which row is the first and which the second. Then use conditional aggregation over that.

The calculation you are looking for appears to be `100 - SecondValue * 100 / FirstValue`

```sql
SELECT
  t1.emp_id,
  [percent] = 100 - MIN(CASE WHEN t1.rn = 2 THEN t1.salary END) * 100.0 / MIN(CASE WHEN t1.rn = 1 THEN t1.salary END)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.emp_id ORDER BY t1.in_date)
    FROM test1 t1
) t1
GROUP BY
  t1.emp_id
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=533b8ea5a9fefde9bb520386afa069bd)

If you could have more than two rows per `emp_id` then you need something to identify the last row

```sql
SELECT
  t1.emp_id,
  [percent] = 100 - MIN(CASE WHEN t1.NextDate IS NULL THEN t1.salary END) * 100.0 / MIN(CASE WHEN t1.rn = 1 THEN t1.salary END)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.emp_id ORDER BY t1.in_date),
      NextDate = LEAD(t1.in_date) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.emp_id ORDER BY t1.in_date)   -- will be null on the last row
    FROM test1 t1
) t1
GROUP BY
  t1.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may subselect the max and min date and then choose those salaries to calculate by joining by date

```
select distinct e.emp_id, 
( CAST((maxsal.salary-minsal.salary)*100  AS DECIMAL(10,2))/ CAST(minsal.salary AS DECIMAL(10,2)) )  as salary_increase_from_first_to_last_salary
 FROM test1 E
 join (
   select emp_id, salary FROM test1 EE where in_date = 
    (select min(in_date) FROM test1 EEE where EEE.emp_id = EE.emp_id)
  ) as minsal on minsal.emp_id = e.emp_id
 join (
   select emp_id, salary FROM test1 EE where in_date = 
    (select max(in_date) FROM test1 EEE where EEE.emp_id = EE.emp_id)
  ) as maxsal on maxsal.emp_id = e.emp_id
;
```

You may need to adapt the casts, or you may not need them at all.

Of course, if the table is big this may not be the best way performancewise and you may need to analise its plan before you accept it. Probably you can find a best way using other subselects or grouping, but this is the most obvious way IMHO by pure SQL.

Comment: I hadn't seen @charlieface answer; probably better with regard performance if it takes sqlserver features...